# What does self. mean in a class method?

Tags: ruby

In Programming Ruby, I saw a class method is defined as

```
class File
  def self.my_open(*args)
  #...
  end
end
```

What does the prefix "self." mean here?

Comment: From the [first match](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby) in a Google search for "Ruby Self" : *"The keyword self in Ruby gives you access to the current object – the object that is receiving the current message."*

Comment: [This article](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby) gives an excellent explanation on `self` in `Ruby`.

Comment: Yep.  That's the one I linked also.

Comment: I don't the question is that bad. The `self` in `def self.foo` indeed means the class it is placed into, but then, it becomes unclear why `def foo` does not mean the same thing since omission of `self` as receiver usually has no effect. And I think that is the real point of the question.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa. I was in the middle of composing an answer when the question got closed. :)

Comment: When I started programming Ruby, I vaguely understood that you use `def self.foo` for "class" methods, and `def foo` for instance methods, but I didn't really understand why. So I think it's a fair enough question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using syntax `def receiver.method` you can define methods on a *specific objects*.

```
class Dog
  def bark
    puts 'woof'
  end
end

normal_dog = Dog.new
angry_dog = Dog.new


def angry_dog.bite
  puts "yum"
end


normal_dog.class # => Dog
angry_dog.class # => Dog

angry_dog.bite # >> yum
normal_dog.bite # ~> -:15:in `<main>': undefined method `bite' for #<Dog:0x007f9a93064cf0> (NoMethodError)
```

Note that even though dogs are of the same class `Dog`, one of them has a unique method that another dog doesn't.

The same thing with classes. Inside of class definition, `self` points to that class. This is critical to understanding.

```
class Foo
  self # => Foo
end
```

Now let's look at these two classes:

```
class Foo
  def self.hello
    "hello from Foo"
  end
end

class Bar
end

Foo.class # => Class
Bar.class # => Class


Foo.hello # => "hello from Foo"
Bar.hello # ~> -:15:in `<main>': undefined method `hello' for Bar:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Even though both `Foo` and `Bar` are both **instances** (objects) of class `Class`, one of has a method which another doesn't. The same thing.

If you omit the `self` in method definition, then it becomes *instance method* and it will be available on *instances* of a class rather than on the class itself. See the `Dog#bark` definition in the first snippet.

For closing, here's a couple more methods of how you can define a class instance method:

```
class Foo
  def self.hello1
    "hello1"
  end

  def Foo.hello2
    "hello2"
  end
end

def Foo.hello3
  "hello3"
end


Foo.hello1 # => "hello1"
Foo.hello2 # => "hello2"
Foo.hello3 # => "hello3"
```

Comment: Hi thank you @SergioTulentsev - so basically self.method_name allow methods to be called on a class directly, without having to create an instance of the class?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: something like this, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Sergio does a fantastic job of explaining it. I thought I would add to it by making it more simple for noobs (with the utmost respect) - who may struggle to understand the above answer.

**(1) What is a method?**

Think of a human. A human can do certain actions. e.g. we can walk, talk, drive, drink copious amounts of alcohol etc. These types of actions are called: "methods".

**(2) There are some methods which can be performed only by some people**

For example, only Tiger Woods can drive a ball 330 yards with a beautiful tiny fade. Not all human beings can perform this method......Another example: only Michael Jackson can sing and moon walk like a King.

Let us suppose we create a person. (i.e. we are creating a person object).

```
Freddie_Mercury = Person.new

Freddie_Mercury.DriveGolfBall # ~> -:15:in `<main>': undefined method `DriveGolfBall' for Person:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Freddie can't drive golf balls. That method is not a "class method"

**(3) The "Self" prefix creates methods which all people can do. It creates class methods**

If I want to create a method which every single human being in the world can do: it would be the: breath method. All people can breathe. If they couldn't, they would die.

**(4) How would I call the method?**

If I wanted some breathing to be done, I would say "Person.breathe". I would not say "FreddieMercury.breathe". There would be no need to call the method on a particular person, but I would call the method on the entire species: I would call it on the Person class.